# GCC 4.7 on OS X Lion: cannot compute suffix of object files

Tags: osx-lion, gcc4.7

I know this issue already discussed (include there), and no one time. But, unfortunately, I cannot solve this problem.

So, I have OS X Lion, i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1, and I try to build gcc-4.7.0.

First of all, I've already built this compiler on Debian GNU/Linux, so I was sure any problems will not be...

So, I read [this GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) and I did all exactly as described:

```
cd gcc-4.7.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir gcc_build
cd gcc_build
/Users/dshevchenko/Downloads/gcc-4.7.0/configure --prefix=/Users/dshevchenko/Tools/GCC 
make
```

So, MPC, MPFR and GMP was successfully downloaded, and **./configure** was OK. But after few minutes after **make** I get this error:

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: 
in `/Users/dshevchenko/Downloads/gcc_build/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

As I understand this can't be due error of dynamic linking with MPFR, MPC or GMP, because these libs was built inside of GCC source code tree.

In my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/dshevchenko/Tools/GCC/lib
```

Help me please, I'll be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Ok, it's done. I found solution on one discussion: just set variables CC and CXX as gcc-4.2 and g++-4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have the latest Xcode (4.4 at the time of this writing).  There is a bug in the llvm compiler in some versions of Xcode (including 4.1, which I had).  For Xcode 4.4, the command line tools must be downloaded from the Xcode preferences.

Answer (score 0):

the follow solution helped me out:

```
$ export CC="gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0”
$ $srcdir/configure ...
$ make
```

source: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50342